# react port localhost//3001/login not found

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

[image: this is the error which is i am getting again and again it was working fine but suddenly it stopped working.]

I am trying to make a post request through axios but it is not working and console log error shows saying that react localhost//3001/login not found.

Here is my main login page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import touristUserModel from "../../models/User/user";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Sign_in } from "../../dao/firebase";
import UserType from "../../config/config";
import { checkNull } from "../../helpers/data-type-check";
import executeEndpoint from "../../dao/api";
import routes from "../../routes/routes";

function Login(props) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [userLoginData, setuserLoginData] = useState(touristUserModel);

  function handleUser(e) {
    setuserLoginData({
      ...userLoginData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  const SignIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Sign_in(userLoginData, (response) => {
      setuserLoginData({ ...userLoginData, _id: response.user.uid });

      if (checkNull(response)) {
        executeEndpoint({
          method: 'post',
          url: routes.api.tourist.data.url,
          data: {
            ...userLoginData,
            _id: response.user.uid,
          },

          onResponse: (response) => {
            const { ...data } = response.data;
            console.log(data);
            if (data.user_type === UserType.tourist) {
              history.push(routes.web.tourist.path);
            } else if (data.user_type === UserType.guide) {
              history.push(routes.web.guide.path);
            } else {
              history.push(routes.web.post.path);
            }
          },
          onError: (error) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
          },
        });
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={SignIn}>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Label> Enter Email </Form.Label>{" "}
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            value={userLoginData.tourist_email}
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            name={"email"}
            onChange={handleUser}
          />{" "}
        </Form.Group>{" "}
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Label> Enter Password </Form.Label>{" "}
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            value={userLoginData.tourist_password}
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            name={"password"}
            onChange={handleUser}
          />{" "}
        </Form.Group>{" "}
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Login{" "}
        </Button>{" "}
      </Form>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

api component

```
import axios from "axios";
import ApiParams from "../models/api/api-params";

/**
 *
 * @param {ApiParams} apiparams
 *
 */
// const method = ''; const url = ''; const data = {}; const onResponse= ({}) => {}; const onError = ({}) => {};
const executeEndpoint = async (apiparams) => {
  const { method, url, data, onResponse, onError } = ApiParams;

  const config = {
    method: method,
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    data: data,
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      onResponse(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      onError(error);
    });
};

export default executeEndpoint;
```

routes

```
import Post from "../pages/admin/post/post";
import Login from "../pages/auth/login";
import Registration from "../pages/auth/registration";
import GuidePage from "../pages/guide/guide";
import TouristPage from "../pages/tourist/tourist";

const Routes = {
  web: {
    registration: {
      path: "/registration",
      component: <Registration />,
    },
    login: {
      path: "/login",
      component: <Login />,
    },
    post: {
      path: "/post",
      component: <Post />,
    },
    tourist: {
      path: "/tourist",
      component: <TouristPage />,
    },
    guide: {
      path: "/guide",
      component: <GuidePage />,
    },
  },
  api: {
    tourist: {
      create: {
        url: "http://localhost:3000/tourist/create",
      },
      data: {
        url: "http://localhost:3000/tourist/get",
      },
    },
    country: {
      fetch:{
        url:"http://localhost:3000/country/get"
      }
    },
    Place:{
      create:{
        url:"http://localhost:3000/place/create"
      }
    }
  },
};

export default Routes;


const ApiParams = {
    method: "",
    url: "",
    data: {},
    onResponse: ({}) => {},
    onError: ({}) => {}
}

export default ApiParams
```

Comment: Are you running your code on PORT 3000, or 3001? The title & image doesn't match description and code. If you've a local server running have you ensured it's *actually* running and reachable?

Comment: i am running react on port 3001 and express is running on port 3000

Comment: it was working fine but suddenly it stopped working if call axios directly like(axios.post("localhost:3000/tourist/get") then it works fine but api.js file is not working correctly

Comment: Your screenshot displays `3001` instead of `3000`. I believe that you should either update the screenshot or update the question.

Comment: yeah i have updated the question but i dont know how to add the image in a proper way so i have to undo the image setting which was changed by @DrewReese sorry bro

Comment: In the editor where you can add an image you can simply paste the URL. I rolled back and applied your port number update.

Comment: thanks bro i have never posted any question on this platform before thats why i am have issue but the main issue is not resolved yet :p